# Rest API Web Service - iOS

Tags: web-services, rest

Its my first time to use web service in iOS.
REST was my first choice and I use code igniter to form it.

I have my Controller:

```
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Sample extends REST_Controller
{

    function example_get()
    {
        $this->load->helper('arh');
        $this->load->model('users');

        $users_array = array();
        $users = $this->users->get_all_users();

        foreach($users as $user){
            $new_array = array( 
                                'id'=>$user->id , 
                                'name'=>$user->name,
                                'age'=>$user->age,
                              );
            array_push( $users_array, $new_array);
        }

        $data['users'] = $users_array;      
        if($data)
        {
            $this->response($data, 200);
        }
    }

    function user_put()
    {  
        $this->load->model('users');
        $this->users->insertAUser();

        $message = array('message' => 'ADDED!');
        $this->response($message, 200);

    } 

}
```

, using my web browser, accessing the URL `http://localhost:8888/restApi/index.php/sample/example/format/json` really works fine and gives this output:

```
{"users":[{"id":"1","name":"Porcopio","age":"99"},{"id":"2","name":"Name1","age":"24"},{"id":"3","name":"Porcopio","age":"99"},{"id":"4","name":"Porcopio","age":"99"},{"id":"5","name":"Luna","age":"99"}]}
```

, this gives me a great output using RKRequest by RestKit in my app.

The problem goes with the put method. This URL :

```
http://localhost:8888/restApi/index.php/sample/user
```

always give me an error like this:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<xml>
<status/>
<error>Unknown method.</error>
```

This is my Users model

```
<?php

    class Users extends CI_Model {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function get_all_users()
        {
            $this->load->database();
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->result();
        }

        function insertAUser(){
            $this->load->database();
            $data = array('name'=> "Sample Name", 'age'=>"99");
            $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

What is the work around for my _put method why am I not inserting anything?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem by using Firefox plug in rest Client.
I just have to indicate the headers and the body to make put and post work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you set the method to `PUT` or `POST`, your web server is not going to treat it as such. When you enter URLs in a browser bar, that is almost always a GET request. You might try to use `curl` like

```
curl -X POST -d @filename http://your.url.path/whatever
```

Another link would be: https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

So you should be able to do a PUT similarly (perhaps with no data). Not really sure if this should be iOS tagged though :)

Comment: I'm really confused so I tagged iOS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136971/rest-web-service-for-reskit