# REST Web Service for ResKit

Tags: ios, rest, restkit

I am quite confused on what REST API to follow that will sync with RestKit.
I have a problem in making a put/post/delete request.

One of the REST API I follow is from [NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) which I found very hard to sync with RestKit.

Any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RestKit is a generalized framework for consuming JSON/XML over HTTP. It will interoperate with any backend, providing the payload can be expressed as key-value coding key paths.

Comment: Thanks! For example I want to use put on a client with no parameters and my backend code for that in the REST API does simple insert. How can this be done?

Comment: @zeekerg, follow the tutorial that Blake wrote at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md

Comment: I've got the web service and RESTKit running. Thank you so much!